# Integrate SharePoint User links with MySites

Tags: user-profile, my-site, user

In staging, if you click on a user link (for example, on a permissions page, or the 'modified by' column in a document library), it automatically goes to our staging MySites site.  With fiddler, I see that the user link is actually pointing to the /_layouts/userdisp.aspx page, which is redirecting to MySites.

In production, clicking on a user link stays in the same web app, bringing up the /_layouts/userdisp.aspx page (i.e. it does not redirect.)

Is there a setting somewhere that controls whether to perform these redirects?

Answer (score 1):

My Web Application that was not working properly did not have a service application association set up to the User Profile Service. Once I created one and ran a sync, the /_layouts/userdisp.aspx automagically started redirecting to MySites.

The service application association can be established as follows:

Go to Central Admin, and select "Application Management", then choose "Configure Service Application Associations".  Then select your web application and add the User Profile Service Application to it.